# Oracle LINQ error unsigned byte

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, unsigned

I have two oracle tables with key columns Number(11,0). Entity Framework classes have these as longs

```
RESULT
        public long SEQ_NO { get; set; }
        public long ANALYSIS_SEQ_NO { get; set; }

ANALYSIS
        public long SEQ_NO { get; set; }
```

using `web.config` edm mappings :

```
LINQ code resulting in the error:
    var result = db.RESULT.Where(r => r.ANALYSIS_SEQ_NO == a.SEQ_NO);
    var rslts = result.ToList();
```

results in the error:

```
Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.
```

Where should I look to resolve this?

Comment: Look at the table definitions and column mappings.

Comment: please see: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8303

Comment: In checking my logs, the error does not happen for all values of a.SEQ_NO. The LINQ succeeds for keys > 4958243 and fails for values equal to or less than 4958243. All of these values are valid longs

Comment: The mappings in web.config match the long type in the table definition.           <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="10" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />